# How to change a table row color when clicked and back to what it was originally when another row clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title explains, I wish to change the color of a row when it is clicked then revert the color when another is clicked, however still change the color of the newly clicked row.

A resolution in JQuery would be much appreciated. I just can't crack this one.
What I have so far but it's not working for me.

```
function loadjob(jobIDincoming, currentID){
$("#joblistingDetail").load('jobview.php' , {jobID: jobIDincoming}).hide().fadeIn('100');
var last = new Array();
last.push(currentID);
$(last[last.length-1]).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'white');
$(currentID).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');};
```

Comment: Just for general knowledge, you don't need to add a semicolon after a closing curly. `};` is unnecessary. Just use `}`

Comment: If you use click method beware you will have to re bind it if the table is dynamic. $.on is the preferred method to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to complicate things. This is as simple as possible.

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
   $("table tr").css("background", "#fff"); //reset to original color
   $(this).css("background", "#fo0"); //apply the new color
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that, had a feeling there was a simpler way of doing things. ^^

Answer (score 1):

you haven't shown the marup so

```
$(document).delegate("tr","click",function(e){
  $("tr").css('background-color', 'white');
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ymd65/25/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function(e){
    // reset rows
    $('tr').css('background-color', 'white');
    // set colour of row raising the click event 
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Also I would use $.on as its cool...read up on why it is!

Answer (score 0):

ou can use a class, like this:

```
.selected td { background-color: #CCC; }
```

Then apply it when clicked using `.delegate()`, like this:

```
$("#tab1").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
   $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ymd65/